# complicated anti-hotlinking

Tags: .htaccess

I have a quite complicated hotlinking problem. Since I my understanding of .htaccess is kinda terrible, I'll pseudo-code it:

1:Every embedded Image call should redirect to a "do not hotlink" image

2:Every direct hit to an image with let's say: domain.com/folder/IMAGENAME.jpg should redirect to my page containing the image e.g. domain.com/IMAGENAME.html

3:search engines should be unaffacted or at least still be able to crawl them for image searches

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Q: So what exactly are you trying to do?  What is your question?

Comment: Let's say i have the page domain.com/lol-cat.html which mainly contains lol-cat.jpg. Now someone sends "domain.com/lol-cat.jpg" to a friend. When his friend clicks the link, I want it to redirect to domain.com/lol-cat.html . But it shouldn't break the indexing by search engines

Comment: There's no way to tell the difference between **1** and **2**, in both cases, the referer [sic] is the same thing.

Comment: Jon Lin is correct.  But I'm really wondering what you hope to accomplish?  Are you trying to "protect" your .jpg against "theft"?  Or insure that you can't see the .jpg without viewing the page?  Or what, exactly???

Comment: I wanna turn "bad" traffic into "good" traffic. So that people instead  of only looking at that one picture, also see my page, other pictures and ads

Comment: You'd need to choose either **1** or **2**, but not both because you can't tell whether someone clicked on a link for an image or embedded it with an `<img>` tag.

Comment: will all embeds break, when I go for solution #2 ?